# Inno Setup : Displaying a Bitmap Image in a `NotebookPage` or `NotebookForm`

Tags: inno-setup

Hello I made an Inno Setup Script which has a custom uninstaller forms during uninstall of the program.

Those uninstaller forms are created by me according to the way described in this post(question):

- [*Custom Uninstall Page (not MSGBOX).*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415457/custom-uninstall-page-not-msgbox/%20%22Custom%20Uninstall%20Page%20(not%20MSGBOX).)

*But creating Custom Forms like that is looking bit bad because there is no way to display any kind of "IMAGE" in those.*

I want to display one same`Bitmap Image` in all of my notebook pages whose displayed after pressing "Yes" to the message box `Are you sure....?`.

Displaying this in a `Notebook Page` is very hard.How can I do this?

My `Bitmap Image` should be in the bottom of the `Notebook Page`.

- [*An image of the first `Notebook Page` I created.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORusk.jpg)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You did'n really explain what particular problem you have with implementing this.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it is a how-to question and not a problem.

Comment: "Is very hard" sounds like a problem to me. If your only problem is how to add new image, why are you making your question specific to uninstaller and notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Put the image outside of the notebook and make sure the notebook does not cover the space reserved for the image. This is the way the installer wizard is implemented.

Or just clone the image on all pages.

To add a new image, use `TBitmapImage.Create`. See for example: [inno setup bmp image appear on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12939103/850848)

Comment: But I don't know how to apply image to it.When I try using `NotebookPage.WizardSmallBitmapImage` compiler error `"Unknown Identifier - WIZARDSMALLBITMAPIMAGE"` occurs. How can I apply image?Any example code to do so?

Comment: But `TBitmapImage.Create` is only supported for the WizardForms.I created a `NotebookForm` and not a `WizardForm` !

Comment: That's not true. Did you try?

Comment: Yes ..........I created my additional three forms using the function : `function CreateNotebookForm: TSetupForm;`.I need to display .BMP in this form (`NotebookForm`).But how can I do it? I don't know  how to use `TBitmapImage.Create` in a `NotebookForm`.Please tell me how.

Comment: The same way as every where else, just make the custom form an owner of the image (by passing the form to the `.Create`) and set the `.Parent` properly (the form itself or the notebook). I cannot be more concete as your question is still quite uncler and you didn't show us any code.